# Build Qt with QtMultimedia support

Tags: c++, qt, build, qtmultimedia

I have downloaded qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0 and build it with configure options witn mingw32 on WIndows 7:

```
configure -static -release -platform win32-g++ -openssl -I C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -L C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\MinGW -target xp -no-directwrite -no-angle -no-opengl -static-runtime -wmf-backend -audio-backend
```

I get "Unknown module(s) in QT: multimedia" from the .pro when including QT += multimedia.

In directory  'C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0\' or 'C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0\qtbase\include' not exist folder named qtmultimedia.

I found this: [qtmultimedia-opensource-src-5.6.0.7z](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.6/5.6.0/submodules/)

How i can add QtMultimedia support in my QT.

Comment: Do you really want to compile it ? Or do you just want to get Qt ?

Comment: @GabrieldeGrimouard de Grimouard i want Qt with QtMultimedia. I build sucessufully Qt (static version + static-runtime + openssl(static) + Xp support) without QtMultimedia. My question is how i can compile Qt + QtMultimedia.

Comment: So you want a static version of Qt ? Do you know that then, if you do a commercial application you will need a commercial license ? To just get Qt with Multimedia support you can just download qt from here https://www.qt.io/download/

Comment: yes i know, my app is not a commercial for now.

Comment: Then why would you want a static version of Qt ?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to build `qt multimedia` module statically. I can't see any error in the parameters that you pass to configure. Adding `-make libs` can work. However, I've build static versions of qt many times, and I always get support for Qt Multimedia. There are the parameters that I usually use to build Qt on Windows:
`configure -prefix "/somePath/Qt511Static" -static -static-runtime -release -opensource -confirm-license -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -sql-sqlite -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine`

Also make sure you install the static version of qt correctly and also set a new static kit in qt creator.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you ran configure in **C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0\qtbase** instead of in the top level directory at **C:\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.0**

This would have resulted in only qtbase being configured. So when you ran nmake or jom after, you would only get the base modules and not the other modules such as Multimedia.